# Which numbers will remain if I keep removing the second third of the remaining interval?

Tags: fractions

Inspired by this [Google Code Jam problem - Vanishing Numbers](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/842485/dashboard)

> There is a pool of numbers which are arbitrary decimal fractions from
>   the interval (0, 1). In the first round of the game the middle third
>   of the interval disappears, and the numbers from this interval are
>   eliminated from the pool. In the next rounds the middle thirds of each
>   of the remaining intervals disappear. In the first round the the
>   interval [1/3, 2/3] is eliminated and in the second round the two
>   intervals [1/9, 2/9] and [7/9, 8/9] are eliminated, and so on. The
>   endpoints of each removed interval are removed as well.

It seems that if we keep repeating this process, at the end there will still be some fractions that will not get removed, for example 0.3. How to determine which numbers will never get removed, other than by actually repeating the process?

Comment: Look up the Cantor Set.

Comment: As a hint if you don't want to simply look up a solution, consider trinary representations.

Comment: Note that typically in the Cantor set one removes open intervals, whereas in this problem closed intervals are removed.

Comment: @MattPressland Does it matter in this case? Since numbers such as 1/3, 1/9, etc. cannot be represented in decimal fractions

Comment: It matters a bit.  The usual Cantor set includes the numbers that terminate in base $3$ and don't have any $1$'s in the expansion, because $1/3$ is considered as $0.0222222\ldots_3$ instead of $0.1_3$.  But it is a countable set, so maybe it doesn't matter for your purpose.

Comment: @Yohan Not to the answer, but I don't know if other references to the Cantor set will contain statements that break down if you remove the endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a number $0<x<1$ is represented in base-3 by $0.d_1d_2\ldots$ then the first digit represents in which third it lies, when dividing $(0,1)$ into 3 segments, the second digit represents in which third of that third the number is, etc.

This means, that by the end of the process, you remain with exactly all numbers that have a base-3 representation containing only $0$s and $2$s.

Comment: +1 doing it that way leads to a surprisingly simple treatment of several properties of the cantor set...

Comment: How do you know if the base-3 representation of a number x contains only 0 and 2?

Comment: This is neat.  I've never heard it explained so clearly.

Comment: @Yohan If $x$ is rational, its base-3 representation is periodic, and you can simply expand and check. In the general case, the representation may not even be computable, so you can't know.

Comment: @Yohan The representation for the set of all such numbers (the Cantor set), based on this property, would be $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i 3^{-i} : \forall i (\alpha_i\in\{0,2\})\right\}$ but this doesn't really capture the essence.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez how do I know if the period has repeated?

Comment: @Yohan Just like in base-10 [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), just with all the numbers written in base-3.